# How do you make 64 bit wineprefix on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 32-bit, 19.10

I'm trying to run a 64 bit application in wine, and it's difficult on ubuntu 19.10. I tried the normal way with

```
rm -r ~/.wine64/
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64/ WINEARCH=win64 wineboot
```

but that fails with

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/sage/.wine64'
wine: WINEARCH set to win64 but '/home/sage/.wine64' is a 32-bit installation.
```

I see by running `less $(which wine)` that the installed wine on ubuntu is actually a script which searches first for 32 bit wine, then 64 bit wine, and runs 32 bit if it exists (because most people want a 32 bit prefix). This is a problem because I actually WANT a 64 bit prefix to run some 64 bit applications.

What is the intended, or best way of running a 64 bit wine prefix on ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: You can always just run the /usr/lib/wine/wine64 directly, or make an alias if you want to save some typing.

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved this myself yesterday. Turns out I only had wine32 installed, I don't know how I installed it, I think just `sudo apt install wine`, which I expected to give me 64 bit binaries but apparently didn't? Partially my fault, partially weird ubuntu package defaults imo.

Answer (score 12):

Turns out I didn't have the wine64 package installed. After installing wine64 I can just call wine64 directly like

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64/ WINEARCH=win64 wine64 someprogram.exe
```

I don't remember exactly how I installed wine, however I believe I just did

```
sudo apt install wine
```

and expected to get 64 bit binaries but only got wine32 instead. Partially user error, partially weird ubuntu package deafults.

To instal wine64 I ran

```
sudo apt install wine64
```

Thought I'd answer my own question so others googling this can get some help.

Comment: I cannot find the `wine64` binary even after installing `wine64`